# vue router error with firebase auth

Tags: firebase, authentication, vue.js, vue-router

I tried to auth using vue.js and firebase.

and error occurs router.beforeEach function, 
Anyone has any idea why it might happen?

console error

> vue-router.esm.js?fe87:16 [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
>   warn @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:16
>   abort @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1904
>   iterator @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1968
>   step @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1717
>   runQueue @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1725
>   confirmTransition @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1972
>   transitionTo @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1874
>   push @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:2181
>   (anonymous) @ vue-router.esm.js?fe87:1960
>   (anonymous) @ index.js?3672:44

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import addPost from '@/components/addPost'
import showPost from '@/components/showPost'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import SignUp from '@/components/SignUp'
import firebase from 'firebase'


Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'app',
      component: showPost
    },
    {
      path: '/add',
      component: addPost,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/signup',
        name: 'SignUp',
        component: SignUp
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('/login')
  else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('/')
  else next()
})


export default router
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VueFire from 'vuefire'
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(VueFire)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

let app;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    if(!app) {
        app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          router,
          template: '<App/>',
          components: { App }
        })
    }

})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <button @click="logout">Logout</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import header from './components/header'
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
     'app-header': header
  },
  methods: {
    logout: function() {
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
        this.$router.replace('login')
      })
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Login.vue

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

import db from '../firebaseInit'
const postRef = db.ref('posts')

export default {
  name: 'login',
  data: function() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    signIn: function() {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
        (user) => {
          this.$router.replace('/')
        },
        (err) => {
          alert('Oops ' + err.message)
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

addPost.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="add-blog">
      <h2>Add a New Post</h2>
      <form v-if="!submitted">
        <label>Title:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="newPost.title" required />
        <p>{{ getDate }}</p>
        <label for="">Content:</label>
        <textarea v-model.trim="newPost.content"></textarea>
        <div id="checkboxes">
          <p>Categories:</p>
          <label>Vue.js</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="vue" v-model="newPost.categories" />
          <label>CSS Magic</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="css" v-model="newPost.categories" />
        </div>
        <label>Author:</label>
        <select v-model="newPost.author">
          <option v-for="author in authors">{{ author }}</option>
        </select>
        <button @click.prevent="addPost">Add Post</button>
      </form>
      <div v-if="submitted">
        <p>Congraturation!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="preview">
        <h3>Preview Post</h3>
        <h4>Title {{ newPost.title }}</h4>
        <h4>Content </h4>
        <p style="white-space: pre">{{ newPost.content }}</p>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="category in newPost.categories">{{ category }}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>{{ newPost.author }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import db from '../firebaseInit'
const postRef = db.ref('posts')

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newPost: {
        date: '',
        title: '',
        author: '',
        content: '',
        categories: []
      },
      authors: ['Naeun', 'Raphael'],
      submitted: false,
      items: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPost: function() {
      postRef.push(this.newPost)
      this.newPost.date = '',
      this.newPost.title = '',
      this.newPost.author = '',
      this.newPost.content = '',
      this.newPost.categories = ''
    },
    removePost: function() {
      postRef.child(post['.key']).remove()
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getDate: function() {
      const toTwoDigits = num => num < 10 ? '0' + num : num;
      let today = new Date();
      let year = today.getFullYear();
      let month = toTwoDigits(today.getMonth() + 1);
      let day = toTwoDigits(today.getDate());
      return this.newPost.date = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the next function is called exactly once in any given pass through the navigation guard. It can appear more than once, but only if the logical paths have no overlap, otherwise the hook will never be resolved or produce errors.

Your else if condition `else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('/')` violates this rule.

Change your route guarding logic

```
// check if route requiresAuth
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(rec => rec.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    // check auth state of user
    user ? next() : next('/login') // user not signed in, route to login
  } else {
    next(); // route does not require auth
  }
});
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Hope this helps.